# Is it possible to apply seasonal_decompose() after a groupby() where date is not the index of the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, statsmodels

So, for a forecasting project, I have a really long Dataframe of multiple time series of the following type (it has a numerical index):

| date | time_series_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-08-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2015-08-02 | 0 | 1 |
| 2015-08-03 | 0 | 2 |
| 2015-08-04 | 0 | 3 |
| 2015-08-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2015-08-02 | 1 | 3 |
| 2015-08-03 | 1 | 4 |
| 2015-08-04 | 1 | 5 |

My objective, is to add 3 new columns to these dataset, for each individual time series (each id) that correspond to `trend`, `seasonal` and `resid`.
According to the characteristics of the dataset, they tend to have Nans at the start and the end of the dates.

What I was trying to do was the following:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df.assign(trend = lambda x: x.groupby("time_series_id")["value"].transform(lambda s: s.mask(~s.isna(), other= seasonal_decompose(s[~s.isna()], model='aditive', extrapolate_trend='freq').trend))
```

The expected output (trend value are not actual values) should be:

| date | time_series_id | value | trend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-08-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2015-08-02 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2015-08-03 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2015-08-04 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 2015-08-01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2015-08-02 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2015-08-03 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2015-08-04 | 1 | 5 | 1 |

But I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'
```

In a previous iteration of my code, this worked for my individual time series data frames, since I had embedded the `date` column as an index of the data frame instead of an additional column, so the "x" that the lambda function takes has already a "date time" index appropriate for the `seasonal_decompose` function.

```
df.assign(
      trend = lambda x: x["value"].mask(~x["value"].isna(), other = 
      seasonal_decompose(x["value"][~x["value"].isna()], model='aditive', extrapolate_trend='freq').trend))
```

My questions are, first: is it possible to achieve this using groupby? Or other approaches are possible second: is it possible to handle this that doesn't eat much memory? The original dataset I'm working on has approximately 1MM ~ rows, so any help is really welcomed :).

Answer (score 1):

Did one of the already posed solutions work? If so or you found a different solution please share. I tried each without success, but I'm new to Python so probably missing something.

Here is what I came up with, using a for loop. For my dataset it took 8 minutes to decompose 20 million rows consisting of 6,000 different subsets. This works but I wish it were faster.

| Date Time | Segment ID | Travel Time(Minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-09 07:15:00 | 1 | 30 |
| 2021-11-09 07:30:00 | 1 | 18 |
| 2021-11-09 07:15:00 | 2 | 30 |
| 2021-11-09 07:30:00 | 2 | 17 |

```
segments = set(frame['Segment ID'])
data = pd.DataFrame([])
for s in segments:
    df = frame[frame['Segment ID'] == s].set_index('Date Time').resample('H').mean()
    comp = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(x=df['Travel Time(Minutes)'], period=24*7, two_sided=False) 
    df = df.join(comp.trend).join(comp.seasonal).join(comp.resid)

    #optional columns with some statistics to find outliers and trend changes
    df['resid zscore'] = (df['resid'] - df['resid'].mean()).div(df['resid'].std())
    df['trend pct_change'] = df.trend.pct_change()
    df['trend pct_change zscore'] = (df['trend pct_change'] - df['trend pct_change'].mean()).div(df['trend pct_change'].std())

    data = data.append(df.dropna())
```

Answer (score 0):

where you have lambda x: x.groupby(..., you don't have anything to group; you are telling it to group a row (I believe). You can try a setup like this, perhaps

Here you define a function to act on the group you are sending via the apply() method. Then you should be able to use your original code.

I have not tested this, but I use this setup quite often to work on groups.

```
def trend_function(x):
    # do your lambda function here as you are sending each grouping
      x.assign(
      trend = lambda x: x["value"].mask(~x["value"].isna(), other = 
      seasonal_decompose(x["value"][~x["value"].isna()], model='aditive', extrapolate_trend='freq').trend))
    return x

dfnew = df.groupby('time_series_id').apply(trend_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

use extrapolate_trend='freq' as a parameter. you add the trend, seasonal, and residual to a dictionary and plot the dictionary
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
import statsmodels.api as sm

```
date=['2015-08-01','2015-08-02','2015-08-03','2015-08-04','2015-08-01','2015-08-02','2015-08-03','2015-08-04']
time_series_id=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
value=[0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5]

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':date,'time_series_id':time_series_id,'value':value})

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index('date')
print(df)

index_day = df.index.day
value_by_day = df.groupby(index_day)['value'].mean()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
value_by_day.plot(ax=ax)
plt.title('value by month')
plt.show()

df[['value']].boxplot()
plt.show()

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
df[['value']].hist(ax=ax, bins=5)
plt.show()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
df[['value']].plot(kind='density', ax=ax)
plt.show()

plt.clf()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')
fig = tsaplots.plot_acf(df['value'], lags=4,ax=ax)
plt.show()

decomposition=sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(x=df['value'],model='additive',     extrapolate_trend='freq', period=1)
decomposition.plot()
plt.show()

decomposition_trend=decomposition.trend
ax= decomposition_trend.plot(figsize=(14,2))
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Trend of time series')
ax.set_title('Trend values of the time series')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the first piece of code according to my scinario.
Here's my code and attached output

```
data = pd.DataFrame([])

segments = set(subset['Planning_Material'])
for s in segments:
    df = subset[subset['Planning_Material'] == s].set_index('Cal_year_month').resample('M').sum()
    comp = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df) 
    df = df.join(comp.trend).join(comp.seasonal).join(comp.resid)
    df['Planning_Material'] = s
    data = pd.concat([data,df])
data = data.reset_index()
data = data[['Planning_Material', 'Cal_year_month', 'Historical_demand', 'trend','seasonal','resid']]

data
```

[image]